# Dont clear textbox value in php

Tags: php

I am trying to GET the selected ID from the previous form and insert the id into another database. After inserting the data from the form the ID should not be cleared whereas other details can be cleared.

Here is the screenshot of from the form where ID has to be inserted
[Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjrnG.jpg)
When the user clicks on Add image particular ID in which Add image is clicked as to be posted in another form.

After submitting the form the ID shouldnt be cleared. Whereas the other textbox can get cleared.

Here is the code

```
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM abc";
    $result2=mysql_query($query2) or die("Query Failed : ".mysql_error());
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $id= $_POST['id'];

    if( ! ctype_alnum($id) )
      die('invalid id');

   $query = "SELECT id FROM `abc` WHERE `id` =$id";
   $run = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){
    echo "<script>window.open('addimg.php?id=".$id."','_self')</script>";
    }

    else {

        echo "<script>alert('No is Invalid!')</script>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    <table width='300' align='center' border='1' cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0px" style="color:#494949;font-size:12px;  font-family:Cambria;">
    <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>URl Small Image</td>
    <td>URL Large Image</td>

    <td>Add Image</td></tr>
    <?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {?>

   <form method="post" action="report.php">


    <tr><td>
        <input type="text" name="id" class="input" size="20" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" readonly></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="s_img" class="input" size="20" value="<?php echo $row['s_img']; ?>" readonly></td> 
        <td>
    <input type="text" name="l_img"  class="input" size="20" value="<?php echo $row['l_img']; ?>" readonly></td>


    <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ADD IMAGE" class="button" /></td>
     </form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Addimg.php

```
<form name="XIForm" id="XIForm" method="POST" action="addimg.php">
 <h1>News Description</h1> 

  <p> 
 <label for="News_id" class="uname"> News_ID</label>
<input type="text" id="news_id" name="news_id"  type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) { echo $_GET['id']; } ?>" readonly> <br />
                                </p>

 <label for="img1" class="uname"> Img1</label>
          <input type="text" id="img1" name="img1"  type="text"/> <br />
           </p>
```

PHP code

```
     if(isset($_POST['XIsubmit'])) {


$news_id  = $_POST["news_id"];

    $img1  = $_POST["img1"];

    if($img1!="")
    {
    $query=("INSERT INTO images (news_id,img)VALUES('$news_id','$img1')") or die(mysql_error());  
 $retval = mysql_query( $query, $dbhandle );
 echo ""
      if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());


   }
    }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), and you really shouldn't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions.